# Iterate over multiple elements at once Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iterator, iteration

If I have a list like `l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. If I do something like:

```
for i in l:
    print(i)
```

It will print all element separately.

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to iterate simultaneously over multiple elements?

For example, if I want to iterate over each 3 elements

```
for ....:
    print(..)
```

Should print:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

So that in each iteration the variable that iterate the for will be a tuple of, in this case, 3 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over *indices*, and step three at a time, then use a slice within the loop to get the desired values.

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> for i in range(0, len(l), 3):
...   print(l[i:i+3])
...
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Comment: Note that this method works also for lists whose length is not divisible by the length of the slice. For example, for `l = [1, 2, 3, 4]`, it will print `[1, 2, 3]
[4]`

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly the required output you could do this:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

for i in range(0, len(lst), 3):
    print(*lst[i:i+3], sep=',')
```

**Output:**

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
```